# How to make temporary expiring link for a downloadable file

Tags: plugins, links

we need a plugin or code. which work for download link expire after some hour.
like when anyone click on download link its generate a string and its save to db after 24 hour this download link string expire . if anyone come again on same download link its redirect to post area. 
please tell me how to setup on wordpress

Comment: "we need" is not a question :( where is your research? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** You can achieve this using htaccess if you have single download file/path. But if you have more files available for download. Creating a temporary file for each download requests and using htaccess is not a good idea.

```
$path="uploads/";
                  $actualfilename=$path.$filename;
                  $fakefilename="downloadfile.pdf";
                   if($typeofview=="download") {
                          @readfile($actualfilename);
                        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fakefilename . '"');
                        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($actualfilename));
                        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
                        exit;
```

add this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule fakefile.php(.*)$ orignalfile.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Option 2:** 
Creating a symlink() for each file instead is a much better idea. This will save loads of disk space and keep down the server load.

Naming the symlink after the user's session is a decent idea. A better idea is to generate a random symlink name & associate with the session, so the script can handle multiple downloads per session. You can use *session_set_save_handler()* ([link](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler)) and register a custom read function that checks for expired sessions and removes symlinks when the session has expired.

Comment: thanks for reply but we need for wordpress how to use it on wordpress

Comment: This will not be so difficult but you need to spend some time/effort on understanding the resource material on the reference site i have given above.
You can choose between the option based on your requirement and can implement.